# Neo4j + Redis? Good or bad?

Tags: database, redis, neo4j

I making a music app with social networking features. I was hoping to power my database with Neo4j and Redis. In Neo4j I will store user info and all other information ( post, reviews, etc.) in redis. Does anyone have any advice or insight on this?

Comment: Your question is too wide. Really, what is your problem?

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: it depends.

Longer answer:

I'm assuming that you are just starting with the app and want to have quick feedback if it is a thing you want to invest (time/money) in.

If you want to run queries like "which users reviewed the same song" you need to put this data into Neo4J. In general, the more connected data you have there, the more interesting the questions you can answer. So I would err on the side of putting data into Neo4j. Also, only querying one database is easier to implement than aggregating data over multiple ones.

If you get enough users that the amount of data they produce starts to impact Neo4j, you can put the actual review text or post into redis and reference it by an id from Neo4j. But by then you already know it is worth doing and this is a fairly manageable refactoring and data migration.

Answer (score 3):

Neo4j is a graph database. However it does not support sharding (horizontal partitioning). The good thing about using Neo4j is that you can store a graph data structure and run graph algorithms easily with Neo4j query language. This may be useful for analyzing some social network properties. The bad thing, is, because Neo4j does not support sharding, the capacity of the database is limited to a single node. When the data size increases, its performance may be impacted.

Redis is always useful for caching data, which can be a good choice.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will store all user information in each node and all other information will be in the redis database.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I will try to store all in neo4j in the same case.